# YHWH translated to Jehovah 4 times in KJV but not elsewhere... why?

Tags: names-of-god, kjv, translation, tetragrammaton

YHWH is regularly translated as LORD in English translations of the Bible, including the KJV. I grew up as a Jehovah’s Witness and this was regularly used as a way of proving that they knew God because they knew his name was “Jehovah” based on these 4 scriptures in “worldly bibles”.
As an example The Authorized King James Version (1611) renders Jehovah in Exodus 6:3, Psalm 83:18, Isaiah 12:2, Isaiah 26:4, My congregation taught that YHWH should have been translated to Jehovah all throughout the Bible but it was replaced with LORD instead, with the exception of 4 scriptures.

So my question is, why was it translated to Jehovah in 4 places instead of LORD, like in the rest of the Bible? Is there a reason for this differential? What is the reason?

Comment: As part of the research for your question, I think it would help those considering an answer if you were to list the four places you mention.

Comment: Subject also covered in this article: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/18591/why-didnt-the-kjv-translators-transliterate-%d7%99%d7%94%d7%95%d7%94